# Why am I getting "REGDBE_ECLASSNOTREG Class not registered" when trying to create COM instance

Tags: c++, com

Goal here is to simply call method in COM application from a small C++ console app. Trying to understand how COM works with client applications.

The COM application is named "ShoreWare"

The COM component is named "ShoreBusDS.Licenses.1"

The COM interface is named "ILicenses"

The COM method I'm trying to call is "GetLicenseCapacity" (it takes one parameter to determine what "type" of license you're trying to get capacity information for).

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#import "Debug/ShoreBusDS.dll" named_guids

using namespace SHOREBUSDSLib;

int main() {
    // Initialize COM
    CoInitialize(nullptr);

    // Create an instance of the COM object
    ILicensesPtr pLicenses;
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(Licenses), nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, __uuidof(ILicenses), (void**)&pLicenses);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        std::cerr << "CoCreateInstance failed with error " << hr << std::endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    // Now you can call the method on the interface
    hr = pLicenses->GetLicenseCapacity(1);  // Pass license type "1"
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        std::cerr << "GetLicenseCapacity failed with error " << hr << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "License Capacity: " << hr << std::endl;
    }

      // Uninitialize COM
    CoUninitialize();

    return 0;
}
```

I'm debugging this using remote debugger.
It's built in x86 (which I'm assuming is correct because COM component registered in x32 registry?)
I can see using process monitor the registry for CLSID is found correctly:
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID{47D9BA03-36FB-4885-88F6-6C155F4710FF}
Originally I was specifying the CLSID and IID manually and getting the same error.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure the DLL is actually registered with the OS properly? You have a CLSID registry key, but does it actually have an `InprocServer32` subkey that refers to the DLL file? You need to register the DLL via [`regsvr32`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/regsvr32) before you can use it, if you haven't already done so.

Comment: On a side note, even if you get the code running, your `pLicenses` object is being released *after* the `CoUninitialize()` call, which will likely cause problems during app shutdown. You need to release the `pLicenses` object before you uninitialize the COM library.

Comment: *"it's built in x86 (which I'm assuming is correct because COM component registered in x32 registry?"* what's important is client (exe, process) and server (dll) are compiled and registered with the same bitness.

Comment: Remy, thanks! I do see that subkey and the full path to the .dll "C:\Program Files (x86)\Shoreline Communications\ShoreWare Server\ShoreBusDS.dll" But maybe I'm confused. The above .dll is used by the server application running COM. The program I'm trying to run also has a copy of that .dll stored in a different spot. Is the .dll file I'm trying to use for my program also have to be registered? Hoping I make sense.

Comment: Simon, I was able to confirm the .dll was compiled in x32 and registered x32 as well. The exe is compiled in x32. Ended up using "sigcheck" to figure out if .dll was compiled in x32, not sure if there's a more elegant way.

Comment: sigcheck's fine. There can be only one dll registered for a given CLSID (except when running reg-free COM but this is another subject), make sure this dll path is correct in the registry under the CLSID, use procmon to check registry accesses but also file accesses (filter by your calling process name). Also try to CoCreateInstance(... IID_IUnknown, ...) instead of querying directly for ILicenses. Also try CLSCTX_ALL instead of CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER

Comment: Getting REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG when ProcMon tells you that it is registered and retrieved just fine doesn't make sense.  Going for the wild guess: you ran ProcMon on your local machine but the error actually occurs on the remote machine.

Comment: Hans, to clarify, I ran process monitor on the remote machine while program attempted to run, and I was able to see that it did query the correct registry settings in the right location.

Comment: Simon - changing to "CLSCTX_ALL" made this work! Based on what I was reading "CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER" should have been the right choice? Currently running this on the same server COM is running on. If you post answer I will gladly mark as accepted. Thanks again for your help here! (along with everyone else)

Answer (score 0):

Simon's comment about changing CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER to CLSCTX_ALL corrected my problem.